# Not getting the output I want

Tags: c++, arrays, file, text, import

I am trying to write a c++ program to read a txt file containing data (122X300 matrix - tab delimited matrix) into my code and get it to display. The following is the code I wrote after referring extensively to google and many similar questions on this site. On running the code, I do not get any errors, however it does give me huge list of numbers which I cant seem to make any sense of. The following is the code: Any help would be great. I do not know where I am going wrong. Thanks.

DID some changes after considering the comment below by @ZekeMarsh, the problem now is that my text data is like:

[Data Matrix Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWP6S.png)

The output I am getting is this:

[Output of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lz7Cf.png)

The row counter does not move over to the next row,instead continues in the same row after incrementation....No idea why. The code modified is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int HEIGHT = 3;

int WIDTH = 2;
int array_req[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
string userinputprompt, filename;

userinputprompt = "Data Filename: ";

cout<<userinputprompt<<endl;
getline(cin,filename);
ifstream inputfile;

inputfile.open(filename.c_str());

for(int i=0; i<HEIGHT; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<WIDTH; j++)
    {
        /*if(!(inputfile>>array_req[i][j])) 
        {
            cerr<<"Error";
            break;
        }
        else if(!inputfile) // its error.. , can use a cerr here...
        {
            cerr<<"Error";
            break;
        }
        else*/
            inputfile>>array_req[i][j];
            cout<<i<<","<<j<<"-->"<<array_req[i][j]<<endl;
    }

        /* This is not needed, read above comment
        else
        {
            inputfile >> array_req[i][j];
        }*/
    }

for(int p=0; p<HEIGHT; p++)
{
    for(int q=0; q<WIDTH; q++)
    {
        cout<<array_req[p][q]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}

inputfile.close();
getchar();
return 0;

}
```

.
EDITED CODE - The output array is a null matrix. Please help. What is wrong in  the code ..compiles correctly. Trying to read line by line using getline and stringstream based on a lot of examples I read here..still not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>

 const int HEIGHT = 3;

  const int WIDTH = 4;

 const int BUFFSIZE = 10000;

 using namespace std;

int main(){

int array_req [HEIGHT][WIDTH];

char buff[BUFFSIZE];

string userinputprompt, filename;

userinputprompt = "COLORDATA FILENAME: ";

cout<<userinputprompt<<endl;

getline(cin,filename);

ifstream inputfile;
stringstream ss;
inputfile.open(filename.c_str());

for (int i=0; i<HEIGHT; i++)
    {
        inputfile.getline(buff,BUFFSIZE,'\n');

        ss<<buff;

            for(int j=0;j<WIDTH; j++)
        {
           ss.getline(buff,1000,'\n');

           array_req[i][j]=atoi(buff);

        }
        ss<<"";
        ss.clear();
    }

for(int p=0; p<HEIGHT; p++)
{
    for(int q=0; q<WIDTH; q++)
    {
        cout<<array_req[p][q]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}

inputfile.close();
getchar();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Maybe you need to debug it using F-10 key to see what is exactly happening on every line of code?

Comment: @FirstStep Thanks for reverting on this so quickly ...is the code correct? ..how do you tag someone ..its my first time on this site.... O.o oops!

Comment: If it compiled then the code is correct (No Syntax Error). However the problem might be in the values from/to variables and objects(Logical Error). The only way to find it is by Step(ping)-Over your code, statement by statement using F-10 key while checking the value of every variable on your way

Comment: @FirstStep uhh F-10 key? Isn't that IDE specific? What if he's executing from the command line?

Comment: @mwm314 what if I assumed VS because he didn't mention it?

Comment: @FirstStep Why would you assume that? Just because you use it and it's popular doesn't mean fattypanda uses it. I think the idea of stepping through the code is great, but you're liable to confuse a beginner if they're executing from the command line and the F-10 key doesn't step through their code...

Comment: @mwm314 then he will ask and we are here to answer. And how did you "assume" that I am using it? What if I am using Eclipse or NetBeans or even CodeLite? I am sure there is something better to do than to get into this argument so ..

Comment: @FirstStep Indeed, internet arguments are stupid. Just be mindful of putting up IDE specific functionality. What if he's using CodeBlocks? The point is there are a lot of "what ifs", and you shouldn't make assumptions about his environment.

Comment: @mwm314 and FirstStep....oops my mistake. I should have clarified, mwm314 is correct though, I am using CodeBlocks.. :P ...

Comment: 'No errors in coding': if that was true you wouldn't be posting. What you mean is that the code *compiles.*

Comment: @EJP ..I guess I also mentioned - "not getting the output I want". Anyways your comment wasn't helpful. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all during the printing of your array, you are not delimiting your data with anything which will result in a line of numbers. You should add delimiter and line breaks.

Second and most importantly: you try printing the full value of the array while it has not been filled up yet. I believe you meant to put the printing outside of the loop that works with your variable *i* . Now you are printing garbage in the places where the array was not filled yet.

Edit: Here is only the reading part as I believe that is only what you are looking for:

```
for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i)
{
  std::string tmpString;
  std::getline(inputfile, tmpString);

  std::stringstream ss(tmpString);

  for(int j=0;j < WIDTH; ++j)
  {
    ss >> array_req[i][j];
  }
}
```

Comment: @ZekeMarsh...I think you might be right. Let me check once..will incorporate your advice..

Comment: Marsh . I did the changes you mentioned, now I am getting organised output however another problem mentioned above. Could you have a look. Thanks

Comment: @fattypanda To be fair, I don't fully understand what you mean by _The row counter does not move over to the next row,instead continues in the same row after incrementation._  . The reason why you are only getting partial data and displayed incorrectly because your **HEIGHT** and **WIDTH** variables don't hold the values that actually represent the height and width of your matrix. Now the code will only read 6 values (3*2). If you fix that it shall be good.

Comment: @ZekeMarsh..I took those specific values in order to check if the code was giving the output I wanted as per the text file snapshot I posted above. And it wasn't. I tried with other values also. Same issue. The result shown in the image above depicts that the i counter should have proceeded on to the second row as per the text image posted after incrementation, which it didnt. It just keeps moving along the first row and makes that as the second row itself in the final array. Thats the problem I cant seem to resolve. I hope I have clarified to some extent.

Comment: @fattypanda Ah yes, now I understand. However operator>> does not work that way, it simply reads the next value from your file. It does not take your indices into consideration. If you would like to do it that way, you would have to read by lines and only read out as many values per line as you want. I hope that answers your question/concern.

Comment: After understanding your last comment, I tried doing it using some other questions on this site and others. I know I am supposed to use getline() and stringstream for this...I am trying to do this for quite a long time, but somehow cannot get it. could you please help with this. This is my first time in c++, struggling quite  a lot..I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: @fattypanda please see the edit to my original post, I believe this is what you are looking for (only the reading part). Please don't forget to accept the solution if you are fine with it.

Comment: I understood my mistake after going through your edit. Its clear to me now, however I still do not know why to parse a data text file line by line, you have to create a temporary string/buffer --copy to it and then extract from it. I initially thought it would be possible to do it with just for loop itself. I am working on that to understand it but Thank you very very much sir for helping me out on this. I greatly appreciate it. Your edit helped a lot. :) :)